# Can't Locate Ubuntu Openstack

Tags: juju

Tried to install Canonical OpenStack, as per the following document:

http://www.ubuntu.com/download/cloud/install-ubuntu-openstack

1. Already did `apt-get update`
2. Did repository add for juju, maas and cloud-installer

   add-apt-repository ppa:juju/stable
   add-apt-repository ppa:maas-maintainers/testing
   add-apt-repository ppa:cloud-installer/testing
3. Tried to install `openstack` installer, but Ubuntu 14.10 can't seem to find it:

   ```
   root@u1:~# cat /etc/issue.net
   Ubuntu 14.10
   root@u1:~# uname -a
   Linux u1 3.16.0-23-generic #31-Ubuntu SMP Tue Oct 21 17:56:17 UTC 2014 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
   root@u1:~# 
   root@u1:~# apt-get install -y openstack
   Reading package lists... Done
   Building dependency tree       
   Reading state information... Done
   E: Unable to locate package openstack
   ```

Stuck. Please help.

Comment: Using ubuntu 14.10. Yes, I did to 'apt-get update'. Still the same issue.

Answer (score 0):

Did you run `sudo apt-get update` after adding those apt repositories? I've completed the `sudo apt-get install openstack` and `sudo openstack-install` steps with no problem.

Comment: Yes, I did...same thing.

Answer (score 0):

I guess the Documentation is misleading. 
It links to the Ubuntu Server Download Page where presented with the newest Ubuntu Server Release 14.10.
However the PPA Repositorys they use only have Packages for Ubuntu Server 14.04.

Therefore you should try to reinstall the Server with Ubuntu 14.04 and start over.

I tried this several times in the last week, and got till the point where Juju tries to create the Openstack Cloud. But i never got it to finish. :-/

Comment: Oh, and if you're planning to use wake-on-lan to power on your Machines, you should install etherwake and/or wakeonlan on your Ubuntu Server 14.04 Machine, too.